# Linq to sort lists of different kind

Tags: linq, polymorphism

I am trying to make a log viewer displaying events from different sources but ordered by   a time stamp. I have a felling I can use C# Linq for this but how ?

example: I have one list of events read from files into a strig list sorted by a datetime stamp.

Another source of events are database inserts for which I use Linq to extract the same time segment as the first list. The database also have a time stamp.

What I want is to have list showing all events listed as they happen in real time. i.e a dabase insert may lead to an exception logged in a disk file a second later.

I guess I am looking for a way to join and sort these to lists sharing only one common field the timestamp, ending up with a collection I can use foreach over even though each element could be of different kind.

Any Ideas ?

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to transform both data sources to the same type, and then combine them and sort them. Here I have some objects from a pretend database table T_Log which has a Timestamp field and some other fields, and another source is some strings from a fake file where each string contains a timestamp at the start of the line. I transformed them both to a custom class `CommonLog` and then used this to sort. The CommonLog contains a reference to the original objects so if I need more detailed information I can cast and get that information.

A more lightweight implementation could convert to a class that already exists, such as `KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>`.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{    
    // Fake database class.
    class T_Log
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create some events in the fake database.
        List<T_Log> dbLogs = new List<T_Log> {
            new T_Log { Timestamp = new DateTime(2009, 2, 5), Info = "db: foo", Priority = 1 },
            new T_Log { Timestamp = new DateTime(2009, 2, 9), Info = "db: bar", Priority = 2 }
        };

        // Create some lines in a fake file.
        List<string> fileLogs = new List<string> {
            "2009-02-06: File foo",
            "2009-02-10: File bar"
        };


        var logFromDb =
            dbLogs.Select(x => new CommonLog(
                          x.Timestamp,
                          string.Format("{1} [Priority={2}]",
                                        x.Timestamp,
                                        x.Info,
                                        x.Priority),
                          x));

        var logFromFile =
            fileLogs.Select(x => new CommonLog(
                            DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(':'))),
                            x.Substring(x.IndexOf(':') + 2),
                            x
                ));

        var combinedLog = logFromDb.Concat(logFromFile).OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp);
        foreach (var logEntry in combinedLog)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", logEntry.Timestamp, logEntry.Log);
    }
}

// This class is used to store logs from any source.
class CommonLog
{
    public CommonLog(DateTime timestamp,
                     string log,
                     object original)
    {
        this.Timestamp = timestamp;
        this.Log = log;
        this.Original = original;
    }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public string Log { get; private set; }
    public object Original { get; private set; }
}
```

Output:

```
05-02-2009 00:00:00: db: foo [Priority=0]
06-02-2009 00:00:00: file: baz
09-02-2009 00:00:00: db: bar [Priority=0]
10-02-2009 00:00:00: file: quux
```

Update: Martin replied the following in a comment to this post, but it was hard to read due to lack of formatting in comments. Here it is with formatting:

```
var ld = rs.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>(DateTime.Parse(x[0]), x))
           .Concat(ta.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>(y.Tidspunkt, y)))
           .OrderBy(d => d.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot folks! Now I just had to pick a little here and there to get it working :)

As my first list was List<string[]> with the timestamp at s[0]
Second list was of a table class with one element a datetime

Combining all I ended up with:
var ld = rs.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>(DateTime.Parse(x[0]), x))
                    .Concat(ta.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>(y.Tidspunkt, y))).OrderBy(d => d.Key);

And as the value type is polymorphic:
foreach (var m in ld)
{
   if (m.Value is Nettbud)
      ...
   else
      ...
}

Martin

Comment: Thanks for letting us know how you got on. And don't forget to accept an answer. :)

Comment: sorry it's my first time here. Can't see any guidance to formatting, expanding 600chars and marking answered !
Martin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can't format in comments unfortunately - only in questions and asnwers. I added your code to the end of my answer so that it has formatting. If you want to write more than fits in a comment, you can make a new "answer" and link to it from a comment. To accept an answer, just click the tick by the answer to make it go green.

Answer (score 1):

i think the code below should achieve what your looking for.

basically you just need to create a list of objects and then add your lists of db & file logs to that list.  once that's done you can write a delegate to handle the sorting

```
    List<Db> db_inserts = new List<Db>();
    // populate list of db events here

    List<Fi> files = new List<Fi>();
    // populate list of file events here

    List<object> all = new List<object>();
    all.AddRange(db_inserts.Cast<object>());
    all.AddRange(files.Cast<object>());

    // sort the list by time
    all.Sort(delegate(object a, object b)
    {
        DateTime aTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime bTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        if (a is Db)
            aTime = ((Db)a).time;
        else if (a is Fi)
            aTime = ((Fi)a).time;

        if (b is Db)
            bTime = ((Db)b).time;
        else if (b is Fi)
            bTime = ((Fi)b).time;

        return aTime.CompareTo(bTime);
    });
```

EDIT: The code above could be improved using the code below (assume LogItem is a container class like in @Mark Byers reply:

```
    List<LogItem> all = new List<LogItem>();
    all.AddRange(db_inserts.Select(x => new LogItem { time = x.time, msg = x.name, source=x}));
    all.AddRange(files.Select(x => new LogItem{time = x.time, msg = x.name, source = x}));

    var query = all.OrderBy(x => x.time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the log sources, then sort the results. Assuming each log source is an `IEnumerable<LogEntry>` :

```
var logSources = new []
{
    GetFileLogs(),
    GetDbLogs()
    // whatever other sources you need...
};

var entries = Enumerable.Empty<LogEntry>();
foreach (var source in logSources)
{
    entries = entries.Concat(source);
}

entries = entries.OrderBy(e => e.Timestamp);
```